Tranform rotation resetting after input ends in Unity
I've written a pretty basic character controller script and I'm having some problems with making the character rotate to match where he is moving.
Here's the rotation part of the script:
float rotateSpeed = 10f;
transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);

moveDir: Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);
Now, this works fine as long as I am actively moving the character, however when I let go of the key, the character's head goes back to looking forward. Am I doing something wrong? The movement works fine

This is because when you are not doing anything, the inputs are 0,0, so you are affecting a rotation to the player wich makes it look straight forward.
Before affecting the rotation of the player, you should check that the inputs are in magnitude above zero, so that the player is rotating only when moving, and stands in the last rotation when standing still
if(moveDir.magnitude > 0f)
{
      transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
}

